# Antd changing the position of the * in the required fields

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a form in reactJS created using antd, where required fileds have a red * on the left of the label, I want to change that * to the right of the label.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZsVh.png)

I tried to work with requiredMark attribute that is present on the  itself but I couldn't find an attribute to style it or define its position

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
    import './index.css';
    import { InfoCircleOutlined } from '@ant-design/icons';
import { Button, Form, Input, Radio } from 'antd';

type RequiredMark = boolean | 'optional';

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [requiredMark, setRequiredMarkType] = useState<RequiredMark>('optional');

  const onRequiredTypeChange = ({ requiredMarkValue }: { requiredMarkValue: RequiredMark }) => {
    setRequiredMarkType(requiredMarkValue);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      layout="vertical"
      initialValues={{ requiredMarkValue: requiredMark }}
      onValuesChange={onRequiredTypeChange}
      requiredMark={requiredMark}
    >
      <Form.Item label="Required Mark" name="requiredMarkValue">
        <Radio.Group>
          <Radio.Button value="optional">Optional</Radio.Button>
          <Radio.Button value>Required</Radio.Button>
          <Radio.Button value={false}>Hidden</Radio.Button>
        </Radio.Group>
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item label="Field A" required >
        <Input placeholder="input placeholder" />
      </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: I added the code, for the field in the image

Comment: The phrase "Antd changing the position" implies that AntD is changing the position of something. Is that what you meant? If not, don't jam tags onto the front of your sentences. It's confusing.

Comment: @halahlou have you got your solution?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `relative` position to the label.

```
label.ant-form-item-required {
    position: relative;
}
```

then you can change the position of red dot with `absolute` position like this:

```
:where(.css-dev-only-do-not-override-1n7nwfa).ant-form-item .ant-form-item-label >label.ant-form-item-required:not(.ant-form-item-required-mark-optional)::before {
  
    position: absolute;
    right: -11px;
}
```

Check these with inspect element in your browser, you can understand better.[image]